# $f^{\ast}$ surjective $\iff$ $f$ is an isomorphism into a closed set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The result on the title is what I'm trying to prove, so I'll write the whole question, with all the hypothesis. Here $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

*Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism and $f^{\ast} : k[Y] \rightarrow k[X]$ its corresponding pullback homomorphism. Show that $f^{\ast}$ is surjective if, and only if, $f$ is an isomorphism into a closed set.*

I can only get into the basic initial structure of the "if" and the "only if" parts:

- if $f^{\ast}$ is surjective, then for all $g \in k[X]$ there exists $\phi \in k[Y]$ such that $g = \phi \circ f$, as shown by the diagram below.

[image: Diagram]

And here I don't proceed further with much effectivity. I've tried some routes, but was not quite there for me. The closest one was to take $x_i \in k[X]$ defined by $x_i = \phi_i \circ f$ for $i \in \{1,\dots,m\}$ and then construct $x = (x_1,\dots,x_m)$, and here is where I hit a wall again.

- if $f$ is an isomorphism into a closed set, $f(X)$ is closed so I can look to $(\phi \circ f)(X)$. And that's it, I didn't advance further because I was trying the other part.

It is really bad, but I have some ideas:

1. There is a corollary of the nullstellensatz that gives us equivalence between algebraic sets and radical ideals. It could be useful.
2. There is a result that I've shown previously that says: Let $\varphi : A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism and consider the corresponding spectra map $\mathrm{spec}(\varphi) : \mathrm{spec}(B) \rightarrow \mathrm{spec}(A)$. If $J$ is an ideal of $B$, then $\overline{\mathrm{spec}(\varphi)(V(J))} = V(\varphi^{-1}(J))$.

The second one I know for a fact that it is equivalent to the problem I am trying to solve. Finally, I need some help to connect these dots, and I prefer to use the result (2.) to do so. Thanks in advance.

**PS.:** I did read other similar questions, but they didn't satisfy my need to get a better grasp on the subject.

Comment: Also, are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be affine varieties?

Comment: **Question:** "PS.: I did read other similar questions, but they didn't satisfy my need to get a better grasp on the subject." **Answer:** There is also a "scheme version" (Hartshorne, Prop.II.5.10) wich says that for any affine scheme $X:=Spec(A)$, there is a 1-1 correspondence between ideals $I \subseteq A$ and closed subschemes $Y \subseteq X$ given by $Y:=Spec(A/I)$.

Comment: I've seen the scheme version of the problem, but I don't have schemes under my belt yet. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key fact is that the category of affine varieties is equivalent to the category of finitely generated reduced algebras over a field $k$. Here I take 'affine variety' to mean a zariski-closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$. If you define them to be irreducible, replace the words 'reduced' with 'integral' and 'radical' with 'prime'.

Assume $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of affine varieties so that $f^*: k[Y] \to k[X]$ is surjective. Then, by the first isomorphism theorem $f^*$ induces an isomorphism $k[Y]/\operatorname{ker}(f^*) \to k[X]$. Since $k[X]$ is reduced, $\operatorname{ker}(f^*)$ is a radical ideal.

As such, $V(\ker(f^*)) \subseteq Y$ is closed with coordinate ring $k[Y]/\operatorname{ker}(f^*)$ by the nullstellensatz. The isomorphism $k[Y]/\operatorname{ker}(f^*) \cong k[X]$ then gives the isomorphism $X \cong V(\ker(f^*))$ as required.